# Custom photo album category for ALAssetsLibrary is not working in ipad?

Tags: ios, image, ipad, cocoa-touch

I have an image and i want to save that image into custom photo album.

My code is working fine for Iphone but it is not workin for iPad.

```
self.library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];

[self.library saveImage:imageShow.image toAlbum:@"APP NAME" withCompletionBlock:^(NSError *error) {
    if (error!=nil) {
        NSLog(@"Big error: %@", [error description]);
    }
}];
```

just help me please

Thanx for help..

Comment: Do you get any error?

Comment: no,its not storing my image in my costume folder.

Comment: I believe your app requires permission to do this. Does your application have user permission enabled to access the Photos album? Check that in the Settings.app

Comment: But its working fine for iphone.I did not ask anything in iphone .